# Como Escribo i busco un dato dentro de otro en json

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json

Estoy tratando de hacer un script en `node.js` que me guarde los usuarios y el dinero que tiene cada uno de ellos, para eso quiero emplear un `JSON`.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "ID": 222,
      "Money": 222
    },
    {
      "ID": 333,
      "Money": 333
    },
    {
      "ID": 444,
      "Money": 444
    }
  ]
}
```

Esto sería el archivo `JSON`, ahora desde un archivo `js` querría poder leer los `ID` y, si el `ID` es, por ejemplo, `222`, poder editar el valor de la propiedad `money` de `222` y poder hacer un `push` para enviar el dato nuevo.
¡Gracias!

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Para empezar a preguntar correctamente léete [ask] y así aprenderás cómo funciona mejor este sitio. Tu pregunta puede ser votada negativamente porque [no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874) y finalmente [cerrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Aquí resolvemos problemas de codificación donde debeis mostrarnos que habeis investigado, donde os habeis encallado, los errores que os aparecen, etc.  **No hacemos código a medida** (o no deberiamos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías realizar algo como lo siguiente:

```
function UpdateMoneyById(id, newMoney) {
    json.users.find(x=>x.ID==id).Money=newMoney;
}
```

nota: json es tu JSON en una variable. de esta manera:

```
var json = { "users": [{ "ID": 222, "Money": 222 }, { "ID": 333, "Money": 333 }, { "ID": 444, "Money": 444 }] };
```

El método que cree, recibe un `id` (que es el parámetro `ID`) de tu `json`, y `newMoney`, que es el nuevo valor que `Money` deberá recibir. el método busca dentro del array `users`, el `ID` que le proporciones, y le actualiza `money` al valor indicado.
de tal manera que, por ejemplo, si yo realizo la siguiente llamada:

```
UpdateMoneyById(222,1234);
```

tu json se actualizará al valor 1234, el json ahora se vería así:

```
var json = { "users": [{ "ID": 222, "Money": 1234 }, { "ID": 333, "Money": 333 }, { "ID": 444, "Money": 444 }] };
```

Espero te sirva. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo, lo puedo implementar en node.js?

Comment: Arreglado de verdad que muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: no debería de haber problema en implementarlo en node, sigue siendo javascript

Comment: y si te srivió, agradecería que marques como respuesta, mi respuesta jajaja :D

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```
function updateProps(id,props={}) {
    yourjson.users.foreach(x=>{
    if(x.ID === id){
      Object.assign(x,props)
      }
    });
}
```

Donde props es un diccionario que tiene como llaves las propiedades que quieres cambiar o agregar e.g

var props = {
money:200,
regalies:1.50
}

Aquí la función si encuentra un objeto con el id que pases por parámetros Object.assign le asignara esas propiedades al objeto en cuestión